# How to promisify a function for navigator geolocation?

Tags: asynchronous, es6-promise, navigator

I need to promisify this line of code:

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(setPosition);
```

Because the result from it is asynchrounus.

I tried this:

```
await new Promise (resolve => navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
  () => setPosition().then(resolve))
)
```

But is not working...

My code before was like this:

```
const setPosition = async (position) => {
  const lat = await position.coords.latitude
  const lng = await position.coords.longitude
  mapOptions.center = {
    lat: lng,
    lng: lat
  }      
}

navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(setPosition);
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Using Typescript, one possible solution is

```
   const getLocation = (options: GeoOptions) => {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
         Geolocation.getCurrentPosition(resolve, reject, options);
      });
   }

   type GeoOptions = {
      timeout?: number;
      maximumAge?: number;
      enableHighAccuracy?: boolean;
      distanceFilter?: number;
      useSignificantChanges?: boolean;
   };
```